# android device as USB Mass Storage

Tags: usb, android, storage

I've connected my nexus 4 to one of the usb ports on the model b, but it fails to mount the internal storage in /media. How do I get access to the internal storage?

Connected as Media device (MTP), but same results on Camera (PTP).

dmesg's console out

```
[ 8482.187552] usb 1-1.2: new high-speed USB device number 15 using dwc_otg 
[ 8482.289440] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=18d1, idProduct=4ee2 
[ 8482.289479] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3 
[ 8482.289498] usb 1-1.2: Product: Nexus 4 [ 8482.289515] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: LGE 
[ 8482.289532] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 0xxxxxxxxxxx7
```

Answer (score 1):

On my Arch Linux laptop I use `go-mtpfs` for that. In `AUR` there is a git version. Then it is simple: `go-mtpfs <mountpoint>` and you have access to anything.

You can try to compile from `git` directly from [here](https://github.com/hanwen/go-mtpfs).

Raw `mtpfs` never worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I attempted to go through go-mtpfs, but had trouble building it. I got stuck at trying to install the libusb package.

After this, I tried just plain mtpfs and it worked. I followed the instructions from this [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/12/how-to-connect-your-android-ice-cream-sandwich-phone-to-ubuntu-for-file-access)
And used a script instead of the bashrc commands.

```
!/bin/bash
if mountpoint -q /media/MTPDevice; then
    fusermount -u /media/MTPDevice
else
    mtpfs -o allow_other /media/MTPDevice
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to use gphotofs on arch. Mounting via `gphotofs /mount_point` and umounting with `fusermount -u /mount_point`.

(However now I encounter some problems with this tool and can't recall how I've fixed it in past)